Is there a tidy way to type narrow as a result of jest assertions?
An annoying issue I encounter when writing tests looks like this:
function getData(): { isLoading: true } | { isLoading: false; data: string } {
  return {
    isLoading: false,
    data: "hello world",
  };
}

describe(getData, () => {
  it("behaves correctly", () => {
    const result = getData();

    expect(result.isLoading).toBe(false);

    // Despite already have asserted that isLoading is false,
    // Typescript isn't aware of it and
    // I still need to narrow the type by throwing an error
    if (result.isLoading) {
      throw new Error("expected isLoading to be false");
    }

    expect(result.data).toBe("hello world");
  });
});

Is there a tidy way to avoid this unnecessary error throwing?

See this: https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/issues/41179

Same thing you normally do when you have more information than the type system: expect((result as ...).data).toBe(...).

(Or expect(result).toHaveProperty(...), .toEqual({ ... }), .toMatchObject({ ... }), none of which need it to be narrowed.)

You can use declaration merging techniques to apply assertion or predicate signatures to all of the callable signatures and methods on expect as desired… but that seems like a massive undertaking, and one that's more appropriate as a refactor of the Jest types as a whole.

^ That said, it looks like you could be using the matchers in Jest's expect API more effectively: see .toEqual(value) and .toMatchObject(object) — here's an example. If that meets your needs, I can write it as an answer — if not , what did I miss?

The jest API is not implemented in a way that takes full advantage of what TypeScript can do.
You can write your tests in a way that is more TypeScript-friendly like this:
describe(getData, () => {
  it("behaves correctly", () => {
    const result = getData();
    if (result.isLoading) {
      expect(true).toBe(false);
    } else {
      expect(result.data).toBe("hello world");
    }
  });
});

Or like this:
type Loading = { isLoading: true };
type NotLoading = { isLoading: false; data: string };
type Result = Loading | NotLoading;

function getData(): Result {
  return {
    isLoading: false,
    data: "hello world",
  };
}

function isNotLoading(result: Result): result is NotLoading {
  if (result.isLoading) {
      expect(true).toBe(false);
      return false;
  } else {
    return true;
  }
}

describe(getData, () => {
  it("behaves correctly", () => {
    const result = getData();
    if (isNotLoading(result)) {
      expect(result.data).toBe("hello world");
    }
  });
});


I would write a helper function that asserts the argument value is false.
function expectToBeFalse(actual: unknown): asserts actual is false {
  expect(actual).toBe(false);
}

type Data = { isLoading: true } | { isLoading: false; data: string };
declare const getData: () => Data;

describe(getData, () => {
  it("behaves correctly", () => {
    const result = getData();

    expectToBeFalse(result.isLoading);
    
    result;
    // ^? const result: { isLoading: false; data: string; }

    expect(result.data).toBe("hello world"); // compiles
  });
});

TypeScript Playground
